# How to align Text of UITextView at runtime?

Tags: text, uitextview, alignment

I have a NSString that I put in UITextView to display. The string comes from web. It is something like..

```
Duration 1 Day:         $2.12
Transaction Fees:       $3.13
Account Charges:        $4.14
Other Charges           $5.90
Total                  $15.29
```

I want this to be aligned at runtime as I shown. The duration and other cost comes from web service. So I am not able to know previously how to do this. Please suggest how to make text of text view with its cost aligned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by myself. I defined all cost labels in one UILabel (and set its alignment as left) and the costs in different UILabel (and set its alignment as right).